# First 6 ListView elements are continuously being invoked with getView()

Tags: android

When I check my logs, when using ListView, I see, that getView() method of a custom adapter is continuously invoked on first 6 elements, even if I scroll to the very end of the list. Has anyone seen behaviour like this?

Comment: The noun "elements" is not used in Android. I would suggest that you  use nouns that have meaning in Android, so we can tell if you mean "views" or something else.

Comment: Well, it's just some 6 TextViews and an ImageView, bundled in a custom View.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the answer has been accidentally found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/8f3e1891f51f4e34/74169a7c5c06afd6?show_docid=74169a7c5c06afd6).

Just never, ever set ListView's dimensions to be "wrap_content".

Comment: Great info that helped me a lot -- Thanks! An in addition: Just never, ever put a ListView in a container which dimension is set to wrap_content...